# $.ajax() callbacks are not bound to their specific request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tastypie

The code is very complex so  i have simplified below in order to confirm if the behavior i am experiencing is normal or due so some other error i have made in the code.

I have two separate ajax requests that each have their own unique call back.  I do not care which one completes first and one has no dependency on the other

```
function ajax(url, cbS){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data){
            cbS(data)
        },
    });
}

function callbackSuccess1(data){
    $('#div1').html(data)
}
function callbackSuccess2(data){
    $('#div2').html(data)
}

//request#1
ajax(myapiurl+'&peram1=100', callbackSuccess1);
//request#2
ajax(myapiurl+'&peram2=200', callbackSuccess2);
```

The problem: Sometimes callbackSuccess1 gets the data intended for request#2 and vice versa.

It seems that which ever request completes first fires callbackSuccess1 and the second to complete fires callbackSuccess2.

I need the callback to be bound to it's specific request so that regardless of the order in which they complete each request fires it's proper callback.

OTHER INFO:  My backed is django-tastypie, at this point i am thinking that tastypie is somehow messing up the response.  That is the only logical conclusion, given that the javascript seems to be immutable.

The proof that this is actually occurring is that when i inspect the responce on request#1 the data objects are clearly intended for request#2...

CONCLUSION:
Thanks for confirming that 'each invocation of your ajax() function will create it's own closure'.  This was what i thought was going wrong.  I found the problem in my API.  I was doing some funky stuff and it looks like I had a variable that was not getting trashed in time causing the API to return the wrong data if the first request took longer than the second.

Comment: The error you're seeing shouldn't even be possible. Each ajax function  calls it's respective callback function, there's no way in h3ll that they would be swapped, unless you somehow swapped them ?

Comment: To agree with adeneo, here is a fiddle using your sample code (adjusted to use JSFiddle's /echo/html/ route) http://jsfiddle.net/En3xw/ and you can see that no matter how many times you run it - the first div always gets "0" and the second div always gets "1"

Comment: Can you show us a working page on which this occurs?  This would indicate a _major_ bug in the browser you're using, so most people's reaction to your post will be to assume user error unless you have proof.  Browser info would also be useful.

Comment: I agree with you all that I have likely messed something up somewhere.  I'm Just trying to track this thing down..  However, i seriously doubt that i have 'switched them'.  So i guess i am just looking for some clue as to how this could happen.  Unfortunately, there is just way too much code to put up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see with the code you have included is that the function argument is `cbS`, but you are calling `cbs(data)` - note the different capitalization.

Other than that, each invocation of your `ajax()` function will create it's own closure and have it's own arguments and those arguments will be preserved separately for the internal success callback.  This is an important capability in javascript and it works.  It does not get the arguments of one call confused with the callback of another as long as you are not using any global variables or state that might change during the execution of the asynchronous ajax call.

Comment: good catch, but the above example was really just pseudo code.  Not the actual code.

Comment: @arctelix - there is nothing visibly wrong with the pseudo-code you've shared so there must be something going on with parts you haven't shared.  The problem you report is not an issue in javascript.  Each function has it's own closure and save's it's own parameters.  You will probably have to show more of the real code to get help on what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that 'each invocation of your ajax() function will create it's own closure'.  This was what i thought was going wrong.  I found the problem in my API.  I was doing some funky stuff and it looks like I had a variable that was not getting trashed in time.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use jsonp and specify callback query parameter in URL for $.ajax

callback would be the name of javascript function which is to be invoked whenever the response is returned from server.

For more details please refer jquery doc : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

For theory : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

This is mainly used for cross-site ajax calls.